# Unknown SQL coding issue in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm writing an SQL statment that is supposed to do a count based on a date range. But, for some reason no data is being returned. Before I try and filter the count with my date range, everything works fine. Here is that code.

```
SELECT
CR.GCR_RFP_ID
,S.RFP_RECEIVED_DT
,CR.GCR_RECEIVED_DT
,CT.GCT_LOB_IND
FROM ADM.GROUP_CHANGE_TASK_FACT CT
JOIN ADM.B_GROUP_CHANGE_REQUEST_DIM CR 
    ON CR.GROUP_CHANGE_REQUEST_KEY = CT.GROUP_CHANGE_REQUEST_KEY 
JOIN ADM.B_RFP_WC_COVERAGE_DIM S 
    ON S. RFP_ID = CR.GCR_RFP_ID
WHERE CT.GCT_LOB_IND = 'WC'
AND CR.GCR_CHANGE_TYPE_ID IN ('10','20','30','50','60','70','80','90','100','110',
                          '120','130','140', '150','160','170','180','190','200',
                          '210','220','230','240','260','270','280','300','310',
                          '320','330','340','350','360','370','371','372')
AND S.RFP_AUDIT_IND = 'N'
AND S.RFP_TYPE_IND = 'A'
```

The date field I'm using is called CR.GCR_RECIEVED_DT. This is a new field a in the db and all the records are 01-JAN-00. But I'm still doing the count just to make sure I can grab the data. Now, I added this line:

```
AND CR.GCR_RECEIVED_DT LIKE '01-JAN-00'
```

just as a random test thing. I know all the dates are the same. And it works fine, no issues. So I remove that line and replace it with this:

```
AND CR.GCR_RECEIVED_DT BETWEEN '31-DEC-99' AND '02-JAN-00'
```

I used this small range to keep it simple. But even though 01-JAN-00 deffinetly falls between those two dates, no data is returned. I have no idea why this is happening. I even tried this line to:

```
AND CR.GCR_RECEIVED_DT = '01-JAN-00'
```

and I still don't get data returned. It only seems to work with LIKE. I have checked and the field is a date type. Any help wold be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like your date field is not a date data type but a string, that's why `LIKE` works and `BETWEEN` doesn't, between works with dates and numerics. (Well, technically it works with strings but not in the most meaningful of ways)

Comment: I thought that to. But i checked and it is a date type. Sorry, forgot to mention that. i just added it now though.

Comment: Still, try to use the function `to_date('01-JAN-00','DD-Mon-YY')` - you're just passing a string! http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Comment: Not sure about oracle, in SQL Server some formats don't need explicit casting/converting, ie `'20000101'` any `'YYYYMMDD'` will work as a string in a `BETWEEN` or other date comparison.

Comment: Is your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` set to `DD-MON-YY`, by any chance? And are the table dates at midnight on `01-JAN-00`, or do they have a time portion? Those two things together could explain what you see.

Comment: If `GCR_RECEIVED_DT` is indeed a `DATE` then `AND CR.GCR_RECEIVED_DT LIKE '01-JAN-00'` does not make *any* sense (plus you are subject to very subtle bugs due to the implicit type conversion going on there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is set to `DD-MON-YY` then the apparent discrepancy between the first two results can be explained.

When you use `LIKE` it implicitly converts the date value on the left-hand side to a string for the comparison, using the default format model, and then compares that to the fixed string; and `'01-JAN-00'` is like `'01-JAN-00'`. You're effectively doing:

```
AND TO_CHAR(CR.GCR_RECEIVED_DT, 'DD-MON-YY') LIKE '01-JAN-00'
```

Using `LIKE` to compare dates doesn't really make any sense though. When you use `BETWEEN`, though, the left-hand side is being left as a date, so you're effectively doing:

```
AND CR.GCR_RECEIVED_DT BETWEEN TO_DATE('31-DEC-99', 'DD-MON-YY')
  AND TO_DATE('02-JAN-00', 'DD-MON-YY')
```

... and `TO_DATE('31-DEC-99', 'DD-MON-YY')` is December 31st *2099*, not 1999. `BETWEEN` only works when the first value is lower than the second (from [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/conditions011.htm), 'If expr3 < expr2, then the interval is empty'). So you're looking for values bwteen 2099 and 2000, and that will always be empty. If your date model was `DD-MON-RR`, from the NLS parameter or explicitly via `TO_DATE`, then it would be looking for values between 1999 and 2000, and would find your records.

Your third result is a little more speculative but suggests that the values in your `GCR_RECEIVED_DT` field have a time component, or are not in the century you think. This is similar to the `LIKE` version, except this time the fixed string is being converted to a date, rather than the date being converted to a string; effectively:

```
AND CR.GCR_RECEIVED_DT = TO_DATE('01-JAN-00', 'DD-MON-YY')
```

If they were at midnight on `2000-01-01` this would work. Because it doesn't that suggests they are either some time after midnight, or maybe more likely - since you're using a 'magic' date in your existing records - they are another date entirely, quite possibly `1900-01-01`.

Here are SQL Fiddles for [just past midnight](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3a5e/1) and [1900](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bfbaf/1).

---

If the field will eventually have a time component for new records you might want to structure the condition like this, and use date literals to be a bit clearer (IMO):

```
AND CR.GCR_RECEIVED_DT >= DATE '2000-01-01'
AND CR.GCR_RECEIVED_DT < DATE '2000-01-02'
```

That will find any records at any time on `2000-01-01`, and can use an index on that column if one is available. `BETWEEN` is inclusive, so using `BETWEEN DATE '2000-01-01' AND '2000-01-02'` would include any records that are exactly at midnight on the later date, which you probably don't want.

Whatever you end up doing, avoid relying on implicit conversions using `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as one day it might not be set to what you expect, causing potentially data-corrupting or hard to find bugs; and specify the full four-digit year in the model if you can to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. i've been stressing this since this morning. big help

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
WHERE TRUNC(CR.GCR_RECEIVED_DT) = TO_DATE('01-JAN-00','DD-Mon-YY')
```

TRUNC without parameter removes hours, minutes and seconds from a DATE.

Comment: This shouldn't affect the `BETWEEN` since op used a day before and day after the sample date, in a date equivalency check it's certainly a good point though.

Comment: i've already done this same thing using a different date field and it works fine. its goota be the field. as i said its a new field. all the records are 01-JAN-00. i used DISTINCT on the field to see if there are any others and the only othe thing that shows is null. but i did a count and it says there are 0 nulls. so i'm not even sure why its showing me a null

Comment: wonder what this would return:  
WHERE TRUNC(NVL(CR.GCR_RECEIVED_DT,'01-JAN-00')) = TO_DATE('01-JAN-00','DD-Mon-YY')

Comment: i looks like it either made all the dates null or returned the null values, but there shouldn't be null values